# MENU HAMBURGUESA NO CIERRA PARTE 2!

Tags: javascript, html5

Soy principiante!! hice con tutorial una pagina pero el menu hambubrguesa algo le hice mal!! (este es otro pero la verdad Javascript no lo conozco!)  abre, slecciona el link pero no se cierra!! solo cierra si toco el tache, pero de otra forma no cierra!! anexo los codigos a ver si me pueden echar la mano!! de antemano mil gracias!! @guillo

```
<header>
<div class="contenedor">
    <h1><a href="#">Hospital<span>Central</span></a></h1>

    <button id="menu">
        <span id="menu-abrir">&#9776</span>
        <span id="menu-cerrar">X</span>
    </button>

    <nav>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#" class="actual">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#inst">Instalaciones</a></li>
            <li><a href="#servicios">Servicios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#equipo">Equipo</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#contacta">Contacto</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="boton-invertido">Urgencias</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Y este es el codigo Javascript!

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {

const menuBtn = document.getElementById("menu");
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const body = document.querySelector("body");

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    menuBtn.classList.toggle("salir");
    nav.classList.toggle("visible");
    // body.classList.toggle("no-scroll");

});
```

});

Comment: No entiendo cual es el problema.

Comment: ¿Quieres que los iconos del boton se  intercambien a presionarlo y desaparezca el menu correspondiente o aparezca?

Comment: Pulsá en [edit] y mostrá a través de un [repro] ejecutable en la pregunta el problema en cuestión (con el botón que indica `<>`). Además: ¿HTML + CSS + JS puros o con Bootstrap?